# My animation doing a tutorial of jetpack compose does not work, using animateDpAsState

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I was watching the jet pack compose tutorial [Jetpack Compose basics](https://youtu.be/k3jvNqj4m08), but my code does not work in the part of the animation, i literally copy the code of the tutorial but it keeps doing anything, it just show the text and the buttons, but when i click any button the animation is the same even if a i eliminate the part of animateDpAsState.I find something about side effects, but i dont really understand it, and it seems that usually people dont have this problem, not even in the comments of the tutorial video

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BasicsCodelabTheme {
                MyApp(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    var shouldShowOnboarding by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }

    Surface(modifier) {
        if (shouldShowOnboarding) {
            OnboardingScreen(onContinueClicked = { shouldShowOnboarding = false })
        } else {
            Greetings()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun OnboardingScreen(
    onContinueClicked: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text("Welcome to the Basics Codelab!")
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 24.dp),
            onClick = onContinueClicked
        ) {
            Text("Continue")
        }
    }

}

@Composable
private fun Greetings(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    names: List<String> = List(1000) { "$it" }
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier.padding(vertical = 4.dp)) {
        items(items = names) { name ->
            Greeting(name = name)
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 320, heightDp = 320)
@Composable
fun OnboardingPreview() {
    BasicsCodelabTheme {
        OnboardingScreen(onContinueClicked = {})
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Greeting(name: String) {

    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val extraPadding:Dp by animateDpAsState(targetValue =
        if (expanded) 48.dp else 0.dp,
        animationSpec = spring(
            dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioMediumBouncy,
            stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow
        )
    )
    fun change(){

    }

    Surface(
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 4.dp, horizontal = 8.dp)
    ) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(bottom = extraPadding)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Hello, ")
                Text(text = name)
            }
            ElevatedButton(
                onClick = { expanded = !expanded }
            ) {
                Text(if (expanded) "Show less" else "Show more")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 320)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    BasicsCodelabTheme {
        Greetings()
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun MyAppPreview() {
    BasicsCodelabTheme {
        MyApp(Modifier.fillMaxSize())
    }
}
```

I tried to change the animation but it still does not work, im kind of new in this, i know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

The code should work, if not, try to upgrade your Jetpack Compose version to a newer version. (e.g., Bom 2023.03.00).

But there is truly a problem, the `animationSpec` you used is `spring` and you use the value as `Padding`, and that can cause the padding to be negative during the animation, which is not allowed and will case crash:

Padding.kt

```kotlin
    init {
        require(
            (start.value >= 0f || start == Dp.Unspecified) &&
                (top.value >= 0f || top == Dp.Unspecified) &&
                (end.value >= 0f || end == Dp.Unspecified) &&
                (bottom.value >= 0f || bottom == Dp.Unspecified)
        ) {
            "Padding must be non-negative"
        }
    }
```

Use other spec like `tween` is better.